# Quartz, Unity & .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, quartz.net

Is it possible to register a quartz job to always use the same `IJob` instance injected by DI container Unity? I have a  single instance "monitor" of a class `Monitor` coming from Unity DI, wich I registered as:

```
container.RegisterType<IMonitor, Monitor>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

and my `IJob` implementation expects to have that monitor instance injected into it:

```
class MyJob : IJob {
...
[Dependency] IMonitor monitor {get; set;}
...
void Execute()
...
}
```

but when quartz events fire, the `IJob.Execute()` implementation is called before the dependency gets injected. How should I get this working? Should I consider other DI containers or Schedulers instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Quartz will reinstantiate job interface implementation on every fire event. It is [recommended](http://quartz-scheduler.net/apidoc/topic142.html) to use `IStatefulJob` if you want to preserve state between job executions:

> IStatefulJob instances follow slightly different rules from regular
>   IJob instances. The key difference is that their **associated JobDataMap
>   is re-persisted after every execution of the job**, thus preserving
>   state for the next execution. The other difference is that stateful
>   jobs are not allowed to Execute concurrently, which means new triggers
>   that occur before the completion of the IJob.Execute method will be
>   delayed.

From Quartz [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson03):

> StatefulJob
>
> Now, some additional notes about a job's state data (aka JobDataMap):
>   A Job instance can be defined as "stateful" or "non-stateful".
>   Non-stateful jobs only have their JobDataMap stored at the time they
>   are added to the scheduler. This means that any changes made to the
>   contents of the job data map during execution of the job will be lost,
>   and will not seen by the job the next time it executes. You have
>   probably guessed, a stateful job is just the opposite - its JobDataMap
>   is re-stored after every execution of the job. One side-effect of
>   making a job stateful is that it cannot be executed concurrently. Or
>   in other words: if a job is stateful, and a trigger attempts to 'fire'
>   the job while it is already executing, the trigger will block (wait)
>   until the previous execution completes.
>
> You 'mark' a Job as stateful by having it implement the StatefulJob
>   interface, rather than the Job interface.

Another option for you is to implement your own JobFactory:

> Job 'Instances'
>
> One final point on this topic that may or may not be obvious by now:
>   You can create a single job class, and store many 'instance
>   definitions' of it within the scheduler by creating multiple instances
>   of JobDetails - each with its own set of properties and JobDataMap -
>   and adding them all to the scheduler.
>
> When a trigger fires, the Job it is associated to is instantiated via
>   the JobFactory configured on the Scheduler. The default JobFactory
>   simply calls newInstance() on the job class. **You may want to create
>   your own implementation of JobFactory to accomplish things such as
>   having your application's IoC or DI container produce/initialize the
>   job instance**.

Comment: Well, I'm not interested in holding onto the same IJob instance, what I want is to have the same IMonitor injected into each new IJob instance...

Comment: Store the reference to your 'monitor' in JobDataMap or implement your own JobFactory.

Comment: The `StatefulJob` interface has been deprecated... it recommends to use annotations http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/new-in-quartz-2

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Quartz.Unity.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz.Unity/1.0.1

Doc is very sparse, but it appears that all you need to do is add the nuget package and the following line to your container configuration.

```
var container = new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<Quartz.Unity.QuartzUnityExtension>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by implementing your own JobFactory. You'll have to implement the IJobFactory interface:

```
public interface IJobFactory
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Called by the scheduler at the time of the trigger firing, in order to
    /// produce a <see cref="IJob" /> instance on which to call Execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <p>
    /// It should be extremely rare for this method to throw an exception -
    /// basically only the the case where there is no way at all to instantiate
    /// and prepare the Job for execution.  When the exception is thrown, the
    /// Scheduler will move all triggers associated with the Job into the
    /// <see cref="TriggerState.Error" /> state, which will require human
    /// intervention (e.g. an application restart after fixing whatever 
    /// configuration problem led to the issue wih instantiating the Job. 
    /// </p>
    /// 
/// </remarks>
    /// <param name="bundle">
    /// The TriggerFiredBundle from which the <see cref="JobDetail" />
    /// and other info relating to the trigger firing can be obtained.
    /// </param>
    /// <throws>  SchedulerException if there is a problem instantiating the Job. </throws>
    /// <returns> the newly instantiated Job
    /// </returns>
    IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle);
}
```

Then, set the scheduler's quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.type property to your job factory's type.

For reference, here's the default job factory that quartz.net uses:

```
public class SimpleJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (SimpleJobFactory));

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the scheduler at the time of the trigger firing, in order to
    /// produce a <see cref="IJob" /> instance on which to call Execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// It should be extremely rare for this method to throw an exception -
    /// basically only the the case where there is no way at all to instantiate
    /// and prepare the Job for execution.  When the exception is thrown, the
    /// Scheduler will move all triggers associated with the Job into the
    /// <see cref="TriggerState.Error" /> state, which will require human
    /// intervention (e.g. an application restart after fixing whatever
    /// configuration problem led to the issue wih instantiating the Job.
/// </remarks>
    /// <param name="bundle">The TriggerFiredBundle from which the <see cref="JobDetail" />
    /// and other info relating to the trigger firing can be obtained.</param>
    /// <returns>the newly instantiated Job</returns>
    /// <throws>  SchedulerException if there is a problem instantiating the Job. </throws>
    public virtual IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle)
    {
        JobDetail jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
        Type jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
        try
        {
            if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                Log.Debug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Producing instance of Job '{0}', class={1}", jobDetail.FullName, jobType.FullName));
            }

            return (IJob) ObjectUtils.InstantiateType(jobType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SchedulerException se = new SchedulerException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Problem instantiating class '{0}'", jobDetail.JobType.FullName), e);
            throw se;
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting line is:

```
  return (IJob) ObjectUtils.InstantiateType(jobType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomJobfactory that overrides SimpleJobFactory and use spring to instantiate the job classes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom Job Factory
/// </summary>
public class CustomJobFactory : SimpleJobFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Application context
    /// </summary>
    private IApplicationContext context;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomJobFactory" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomJobFactory()
    {
        this.context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new job instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bundle">Trigger bundle</param>
    /// <param name="scheduler">Job scheduler</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        IJobDetail jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
        Type jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
        return this.context.GetObject(jobType.Name) as IJob;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return job
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="job">Job instance</param>
    public override void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
    }
}
```